# DNS Round-robin, Load Balancing, Load sharing, and failover in 2012

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, failover, round-robin

I have been reading many posts on serverfault as well as on other sites regarding all these.

What I understand is, Multiple A records(round-robin dns) can be used for both :

- Load sharing  (round-robin, but **NOT** load-balancing). Many people say that “Load Balancing”
  but I think there will be no load-balancing because “Balance” means (literally) “compare 
  two(or more) and adjust” (and that is what Real s/w or h/w Load balancers do)  but 
  Browsers never do this, instead they randomly select an IP 
  and  connect to it. It doesn't have any knowledge about the current load of that server 
  (probably, the IP it picked had the highest load!).
- Automatic failover (latest browsers only). Yes, I think DNS can be used as a simple 
  failover system (at least in 2012, I dont know when it actually "came in effect"). please refer to : https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10927/using-multiple-a-records-for-my-domain-do-web-browsers-ever-try-more-than-one and 
  [Browser-based DNS failover using multiple A records](https://serverfault.com/questions/247885/browser-based-dns-failover-using-multiple-a-records)
  and http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/dns-failover.html

I would like to make sure my assumptions/findings are right. So let me know please.....

Comment: have you got your answer or not if u satisfy with these answer then u should accept by clicking on right mark.

Comment: No, thats not an answser to my question. That could be an answer to "How can I do Load Balancing?". But my question is, is that possible with DNS round-robin ? I think its very clear from description, where I have talked only about DNS round-robin.

Answer (score 3):

If you want real load balancing for web server's than you should think about Haproxy .
It has high efficiency using reverse proxy and  failover system (keep alive & Heartbeat) Haproxy load balancer will work as a front end server for your web server.

To know more about Haproxy you should read
http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.2/doc/haproxy-en.txt and http://www.howtoforge.com/high-availability-load-balancer-haproxy-heartbeat-fedora8

Answer (score 1):

In Load-Sharing  we share the traffic across multiple paths, even if it is in an unequal fashion.
Load balancing is used to achieve network efficiency. It distributes the  traffic in an even manner across a network which has multiple-paths, this is done to get optimal resource utilization, maximize throughput, and minimize response time.
So these two are really different things.
round-robin when used with DNS(domain name server) is a method af load balancing although it has a drawback that it does not reports automatic failover of a node,even then techniques exist by which round robin technique can be improved.