# Is it possible to setup DNS point to 2 servers, one in Digitalocean another is in Linode?

Tags: linode, digital-ocean

Is it possible to setup DNS point to 2 servers, one in Digitalocean another is in Linode?
I hope the two servers compose a cluster.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. In the easiest case, you just point two `A` records to the IP addresses of the two machines und use them as Round-Robin-DNS.

This doesn't make them a cluster, though. Please explain what you hope to achieve.

Comment: I used nodejs compose of cluster which do not need Ngnix/Haproxy to be proxy server and make auto balance. I hope if one server is down, fail-over auto transfer to another

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and called [DNS Round Robin](https://www.dnsknowledge.com/whatis/round-robin-dns/), but it [might not be](https://serverfault.com/a/101121/274176) as good for load balancing as you wish:

> DNS roundrobin is excellent to increase capacity, by distributing the
>   load across multiple points (potentially geographically distributed).
>   But it does not provide fail-over.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**  Provider diveristy is actually a very good thing.  When one receives a DDoS, the other has a chance of surviving.  Businesses are doing this more and more with CDN's and DNS providers these days.

Public DNS servers are not typically considered to be clusters; in that, they don't need to talk to each other unless one is a slave of the other.  That is not so much an aspect of clustering as it is data replication.  If you have a "hidden master" or use an API to keep your DNS servers up to date, then both would be considered a slave or a master respectively.

Comment: Thanks, having a "hidden master" or using an API to keep your DNS servers up to date is a solution, but updating DNS and activating needs 5 minutes, I prefer fail-over

Comment: What needs activating and 5 mins?  Each server listed in the root servers will be live 100% of the time.