# Temp. Load Balancing

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, load-balancing, cpanel

One of the website on my Cpanel / Centos server on DigitalOcean with multiple domains attracts huge traffic on one particular week in a year, a single server is unable to manage the load and obviously it is important to keep it up and serving the traffic, so in previous years we have setup a second server with multiple A records to balance the load and it worked fine.

Are there any other ways / options with which can achieve the balancing for only 1 static website?

If we go any route, this year we need to ensure that SSL work before the migration, its comodo / free from cpanel - how do we manage this prior to adding the second A record?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Any scale out (multiple node) HTTP load balancer solution could work.

Static only is particularly easy in that you do not care which backend a client selects. [DNS round-robin](https://serverfault.com/questions/101053/is-round-robin-dns-good-enough-for-load-balancing-static-content), or outsourcing delivery to a CDN, become options. In addition to other solutions that might go through a reverse proxy. HTTP load balancing has been discussed extensively everywhere, take your pick of implementations.

Configure the TLS certificate on each host with a certificate that has the DNS Name of the service address. For example, hosts `web1` and `web2` would both have a certificate for `example.com` and `www.example.com`. To test, configure a private test DNS server with the same records as the production one. Use this test DNS server for test lab hosts, and the workstations of whomever is validating the web site still works. Alter DNS by adding the hosts and see what user agents do.